# How to aggregate totals for a given week and each respective weekday?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, aggregate

I'm currently trying to build logic that will independently total each day of the week for the current week given the day the report is run. I need to figure out how to build a query to aggregate each day (and the total weekly sum) as separate columns.

Below I've only provided the subqueries I would use for the Total and Sunday:

```
DECLARE 
@SundayOfCurrentWeek date
, @MondayOfCurrentWeek  date
, @TuesdayOfCurrentWeek  date
, @WednesdayOfCurrentWeek date
, @ThursdayOfCurrentWeek date
, @FridayOfCurrentWeek date
, @SaturdayOfCurrentWeek date
set @SundayOfCurrentWeek = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), -1)
set @MondayOfCurrentWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), 0) 
set @TuesdayOfCurrentWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), 1) 
set @WednesdayOfCurrentWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), 2) 
set @ThursdayOfCurrentWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), 3) 
set @FridayOfCurrentWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), 4) 
set @SaturdayOfCurrentWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate()), 5)
```

/** Select Total Records Within The Week**/

```
( select count(*) 
from release 
where releasetime >= @SundayOfCurrentWeek 
AND releasetime <= @SaturdayOfCurrentWeek ) as TotalCount
```

/** Select All Records As of Sunday**/

```
( select count(*) as SundayCount
from release 
where releasetime >= @SundayOfCurrentWeek 
AND releasetime < @MondayOfCurrentWeek ) as SundayCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       DATENAME(dw,releasetime) as DayOfWeekName
       ,COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
    FROM
       @release
    WHERE
       releasetime >= DATEADD(DAY,- DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) + 1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
       AND releasetime < DATEADD(DAY,7 - DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) + 1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
    PIVOT (
       COUNT(DayOfWeekName)
       FOR DayOfWeekName IN (Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday)
    ) p
```

Lots of different ways of doing it.  I assumed you wanted the results pivoted meaning in columns with the day of the week rather than in rows. So I am showing you one way to Pivot your results.  You can also use the conditional aggregation as in another answer. The trick with Pivot is prepare the table you want first then pivot this can be done with a common table expression [cte].  Then using window functions you can easily get to your COUNT(*) for total count or even a running count as well.

TotalCount
`COUNT(*) OVER ()` --note no partition and no order by statement simply count up the result set.

A running count could look something like this:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(dw,releasetime))
```

Definitely recommend getting familiar with window functions!

Edit, changed the Date comparisons in the where statement.  It will figure out Sunday of the current week automatically and then Sunday of the next week.  The reason for Sunday of the next week is I switched it from `<=` to `<` because SQL Server will round anything above 23:59:59.997 to 00:00:00.000 the next day you either have to make your end date midnight of Saturday if releasetime has a time component or you make it 12 AM the next day and say less than.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(DW, [date_col]) AS 'Day_of_Week', 
COUNT(*) AS 'Count_per_Day'
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY DATEPART(DW, [date_col])
```

Note that Day_of_Week = 1 for Sunday, 7 for Saturday.